# C - Change text colour of single words in Console Application?

Tags: c, windows, text, colors

I am working on a project for school and I want to be able to display the users money back to them as yellow text, for readability. I have so far found a way to do this for the entire window using

```
system("COLOR 06");
```

But this is not what I want. I am running in a Console Application in Windows so some colour would be nice to bring it up to par. Is this possible to do in C?

Comment: You could use ansi escape codes

Comment: @cabellicar123: Does that work on `cmd.exe` too?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling a system command, and assuming you're dealing with Windows application only, you can use the following:

```
  HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, (FOREGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN));

  printf("I'm BLUE ");

  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, (FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN));

  printf("and I'm RED ");

  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, (BACKGROUND_GREEN));

  printf("and we both have green background!\r\n");
```

List of available attributes are available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes)

Comment: There is no way to set just one word to yellow?

Comment: For example the string "You have earned: " would be white, and "$5000" would be yellow

Comment: That seems like it would work but the header file throws a bunch of errors and I can't run the application

Comment: What header files? What errors? Please be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
int main()
{
system("COLOR #");
...
```

# Breakdown:

0 = Black,

1 = Blue,

2 = Green,

3 = Aqua

etc... etc...

system("COLOR ##") // This can provide background and foreground colour to the console

I have not tried this, however you could try set the Colour to display in yellow just before your print, And following the print you could reset it to the default
eg:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
system("COLOR #");
printf("%s",money);
system("COLOR #");
...
```

Comment: I did try this initially and thought it would work, but it changes the entire window background and colour

Comment: @Kyle Jensen Had a feeling that might happen, however I think uri2x had a better solution

Comment: Just as a note, try your code before you give an answer. This is exactly what @KyleJensen said that he did